# Synchronizing a folder between two branches

Tags: git, github

I have created a GitHub javascript project and after having the source in a proper shape, I had later on created the github pages for the project as well. This created, alongside my `master` branch, a new `gh-pages` branch in which the content of these pages are going to be.

Now, I want to display my project working as a demo in those same pages. I had already created a copy of the relevant part of the source, but I find that every time I make a change, I need to make the change on both sides (`master` and `gh-pages`), or what is worse: merge the changes ignoring most of the non-relevant commits (e.g., unit tests).

I have seen subtrees as a way to keep changes synchronized across multiple repositories, but I don't fully understand if it would apply on my case and how.

**How can I achieve having a single folder synchronized across two branches?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout a particular file or folder from a specific branch or commit like this

```
//current branch: gh-pages

git checkout master yourfolder/
```

This checks out the particular folder you want to sync from the master branch to your gh-pages.

Now, you can commit with only the changes in that particular folder.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this out and works fine. It is easier if you isolate the shared section into a specific path, as to avoid merges from one branch to the other. In such a way, I keep my demos and HTMLs on the `gh-pages` and the source code and tests in the `master` branch, and I only need to sync one common part.

Answer (score 0):

I you'd rather not check out the gh-pages branch (e.g. avoid having to stash), you can

```
git commit-tree -p gh-pages -m "" master:html \
| xargs git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages
```

Comment: Didn't know of these commands. If I understood right, what you're doing here is moving the current HEAD up to gh-pages and then committing the whole tree. That should move the current HEAD up to the last commit of the current branch, right? Let me know if I am mistaken.

If not, then what would happen if conflicts arised? How do these commands handle the commit of a whole tree rather than one single changeset?

Comment: these commands are lower-level than commit -- commit started as a script based on write-tree, commit-tree and update-ref. But the tree for your html directory is already in the repository. If you're interested in this, I recommend the gitcore-tutorial.